# Microservice cannot be up when kafka is down

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

Once starting my micro service application after some time kafka is down due to this reason my micro service applications are stopped .is there any way to up my services without depending on kafka ?

Please find below details:

Configuration in my yml file

```
kafka:
    host: dit-grid-kafka.ebiz.verizon.com
    port: 9092
    logTopic: ONEGRID_MS_APPLICATIONS_LOGS_TOPIC
```

In source code:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config= ctx.getConfiguration();

//kafka host name and port number
Property kafkaHost = Property.createProperty(AppConstants.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, 
         prop.getKafkaHost()+":"+prop.getKafkaPort());
Property[] properties = new  Property[]{kafkaHost};
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME); 
//creating the pattern layout
Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                               .withPattern("[%p] %m%n")
                               .build();
//creating the Kafka Appender and adding the layout
Appender appender  = KafkaAppender.newBuilder()
         .withName("org.apache.kafka")
         .setProperties(properties)
         .setSyncSend(false)
         .setTopic(prop.getLogTopic())
         .withLayout(layout)
         .setConfiguration(config)
         .build();
appender.start();
```

Comment: Catch exception and monitor/ignore/alerts/fix etc. - create connection when you need the same or make use of circuit breaker.

Comment: You could write logs to a file instead, then use something like Filebeat to tail these files and ship to Kafka. Then you don't need all this boilerplate configuration of Kafka logging in each of your Java applications (and you can write apps the log to files in other languages)

Comment: Since you're on Spring Boot: I did it with spring-cloud-stream Kafka Stream -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPDzcmqwCNo done this way, your service will need Kafka at startup, but still serve if Kafka is not available (depends also on your implementation).